# How to sort a list of objects depending on it's dictionary of key,value pair

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there a way to sort a list of objects, by it's dictionary of key/value pairs ?
By respecting the order of a dynamic list of names.
for this example it's going to be ["Condition1","Condition2","Condition3","Condition4"]

```
[
          { 
        "uid": "R-T-X",
        "gamme": "MLOP",
        "serie": "XENA",
        "description": "450 - 450 - 8.8 -  - Blanco - / - U3 P3 E3 C2",
        "caracteristiques": [
            {
                "name": "Condition1",
                "value": "450"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition2",
                "value": "450"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition3",
                "value": "8.8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition4",
                "value": "Non rectifié"
            },
        ],
    },
    {

        "uid": "L-M-T",
        "gamme": "MLOP",
        "serie": "XENA",
        "description": "600 - 600 - 9.6 -  - Blanco - / - U4 P4 E3 C2",
        "caracteristiques": [
            {
                "name": "Condition1",
                "value": "600"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition2",
                "value": "600"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition3",
                "value": "9.6"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition4",
                "value": "Rectifié"
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "uid": "M-T-F",
        "gamme": "MLOP",
        "serie": "XENA",
        "description": "750 - 750 - 9.8 -  - Acero - / - U4 P3 E3 C2",
        "caracteristiques": [
           {
                "name": "Condition1",
                "value": "750"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition2",
                "value": "750"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition3",
                "value": "9.8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Condition4",
                "value": "Rectifié"
            },
        ],
    }
 ]
```

I was able to sort it by gamme and serie.

> Lprod.OrderBy(x=>x.gamme).ThenBy(x=>x.serie)

But right now I'm stuck with the last condition that as I said will be dynamic.
So Is there a way to Order this list of objects by passing a list of string

> ["Condition1","Condition2","Condition3","Condition4"]

Comment: In your example, what should the comparator do if `Condition1` is missing?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Fixed it right now sorry my mistake

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to do, but check out dynamiclinq:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/fGXXr1

Comment: @TimBassett my list of caracteristiques may change in the future that what I mean by dynamic. I don't want to hardcode the conditions

Comment: Is this question really [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864427/order-list-of-objects-depending-on-its-nested-list-of-objects) in a slightly adjusted wrapping?

Comment: @AstridE. Unfortunately the part of Caracteristiques couldn't find a way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Assume `caracteristiques` is deserialized as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, I believe you want something like this:

```
var conds = ["Condition1","Condition2","Condition3","Condition4"];
var q = Lprod.OrderBy(x=>x.gamme).ThenBy(x=>x.serie);
foreach(var c in conds)
{
    q = q.ThenBy(x=>x.caracteristiques[c]);
}
var output = q.ToList();
```